# Texture2D to byte[] to String

Tags: javascript, string, unity-game-engine, byte, unityscript

I am having issues in turning Texture2D type image to bytes and then to string. When I do the following:

```
var myTextureBytes : byte[] = myTexture.EncodeToPNG();
Debug.Log(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myTextureBytes));
```

I just get a log output of `"�PNG"`. Why is it so short? Whats the question mark? Shouldn't Unity be able to interpret UTF-8 chars? Also when I send that to my NodeJS server it says `SyntaxError: Unexpected token` and crashes the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that the bytes of PNG representation of the texture is not UTF-8 encoded, which is only for text.

To convert binary data to a string I would recommend base64 encoding.

```
var myTextureBytes : byte[] = myTexture.EncodeToPNG();
var myTextureBytesEncodedAsBase64 : String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(myTextureBytes);
```

Comment: Also you should note that: Base64 will increase the size of the data by 25%. You should be able to send that data as Post data in its raw form I would assume. But my understanding of NodeJS is limited and this may be a limitation of JS/NodeJS.

Comment: Yes, sending it to a server as bytes would be better.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using `Default` encoding?

```
Debug.Log(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(myTextureBytes));
```

Comment: Sorry, but this didn´t seem to work :/ Instead it just prints out "‰PNG"